# Why the npc is shaking/stuttering when walking with a Rigidbody?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I created a short video showing the problem and the settings of the npc avatar and animation and the Rigidbody. Also showing how it's working with and without the Rigidbody.

Is Kinematic is set to true, If not the npc will fall down or in other scenes situations he will float in the air.

And I'm using Animator on the npc with one state of Humanoidwalk to make it move and walking.

The main use with the Rigidbody is to trigger doors to open/close.

[Npc stuttering video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l58yZ7Z-8NY&feature=youtu.be)

And here is a link for the project package I exported it's only 190MB:

[Npc stuttering exported package](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjeFgOHf0UbnaZOo17AOe5ARm4w)

Comment: I think I found a solution, At least it's working. In the npc Animator I changed the property Animate Mode from Normal to Animate Physics.

Comment: If that worked for you, please submit your solution and select it as the answer.